# Ubuntu OS 22.04 would not boot

Tags: boot, uefi, bootloader, boot-repair, initramfs

My default and only OS on my system is Ubuntu 22.04, but just a few days back it doesn't boot into the Ubuntu environment.

How it started:
I shut down the system correctly, but when I tried to put it on, it shows

> No boot devices found.

I was able to boot into the system using live USB and I tried the "boot-repair" option but it came with an error of

> NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr).

I then tried to create a boot entry using `shimx64.efi` and `grubx64.efi`, but they both didn't work.

Please I am seeking assistance on way forward.

**P.S:** when I booted into the system via live USB, I could copy some content from my hard drive to an external drive. And whenever I boot with a live USB, it always carry me to initramfs prompt, I would have to type 'exit' before it exit and continue booting.

This is the link from my boot-repair option: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XKxg7ctNFG/

Comment: Since most proffered solution were not working; I decided to do some back up and reinstall Ubuntu.